# Draw vertex in middle of icosahedron

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection, chemistry

I am trying to mimic a ball-and-stick diagram where a molecule is caged in an icosahedron of other molecules. Using `tkz-berg` I can draw the icosahedron, using code from [this SO question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183061/tikz-code-for-drawing-an-icosahedron-and-labeling?lq=1) How do I put at vertex (ball) in the middle?

One approach is to draw a vertex and delete the edges. I'm not sure how to do that in `tkz-berge`.

```
\usepackage{graphics, tikz, tkz-berge, tkz-graph}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
          \SetVertexNoLabel
          \grIcosahedral[form=1,RA=3,RB=1.5]
          \SetUpEdge[color=white,style={double=black,double distance=2pt}]
          \EdgeInGraphLoop{a}{6}
          \EdgeFromOneToSel{a}{b}{0}{1,5}
          \Edges(a2,b1,b3,b5,a4)
          \Edge(a3)(b3)
          \Edges(a1,b1,b5,a5)
          \Edges(a2,b3,a4)
     \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

Command

```
\grIcosahedral[form=1,RA=3,RB=1.5]
```

draws two groups of nodes (`vertex`) distributed around two circles with radius 3 and 1.5 and center at `(0,0)`. I understand that you want to draw a new `vertex` at origin which is what command `\Vertex` does by default.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-berge, tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
          \SetVertexNoLabel
          \grIcosahedral[form=1,RA=3,RB=1.5]
          \SetUpEdge[color=white,style={double=black,double distance=2pt}]
          \EdgeInGraphLoop{a}{6}
          \EdgeFromOneToSel{a}{b}{0}{1,5}
          \Edges(a2,b1,b3,b5,a4)
          \Edge(a3)(b3)
          \Edges(a1,b1,b5,a5)
          \Edges(a2,b3,a4)
          \Vertex{C}    %<--- Node named `C` at (0,0)
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]