# Please write a code to draw icosahedron

Tags: graphics

I would like to draw the following images on my paper. I tried to import the image using `graphicx`, but LaTeX could not find it (the image is in the same file as my `tex`), so I decided to draw them out. Please teach me what package to use and what code would display the following images. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You can see at here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88760/how-to-draw-an-icosahedron

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code requires the [experimental library `3dtools`](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,3dtools,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{pics/isocahedron/.style={code={
\path foreach \Coord [count=\X] in 
{(0.,0.,-0.9510565162951536),
(0.,0.,0.9510565162951536),
(-0.85065080835204,0.,-0.42532540417601994),
(0.85065080835204,0.,0.42532540417601994),
(0.6881909602355868,-0.5,-0.42532540417601994),
(0.6881909602355868,0.5,-0.42532540417601994),
(-0.6881909602355868,-0.5,0.42532540417601994),
(-0.6881909602355868,0.5,0.42532540417601994),
(-0.2628655560595668,-0.8090169943749475,-0.42532540417601994),
(-0.2628655560595668,0.8090169943749475,-0.42532540417601994),
(0.2628655560595668,-0.8090169943749475,0.42532540417601994),
(0.2628655560595668,0.8090169943749475,0.42532540417601994)}
  {\Coord coordinate (p\X) \pgfextra{\xdef\NumVertices{\X}}};
 %\message{number of vertices is \NumVertices^^J} 
 % normal of screen 
 \path[overlay] ({sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},
    {-1*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},
    {cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}) coordinate (n)
    ({-sqrt(1/6)},{sqrt(3/6)},{sqrt(2/6)})  coordinate (L); 
 \edef\lstPast{0}
 \foreach \poly in 
 {{2,12,8},{2,8,7},{2,7,11},{2,11,4},{2,4,12},{5,9,1},{6,5,1},
    {10,6,1},{3,10,1},{9,3,1},{12,10,8},{8,3,7},{7,9,11},{11,5,4},{4,6,12},
    {5,11,9},{6,4,5},{10,12,6},{3,8,10},{9,7,3}}
 {
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ione}{{\poly}[0]}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itwo}{{\poly}[1]}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ithree}{{\poly}[2]}
  \path[overlay,3d coordinate={(dA)=(p\itwo)-(p\ione)},
   3d coordinate={(dB)=(p\itwo)-(p\ithree)},
   3d coordinate={(nA)=(dA)x(dB)}] ;
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{sign(TD("(nA)o(p\ione)"))}
  % make sure that the normal points outwards
  \ifnum\jtest<0
   \path[overlay,3d coordinate={(nA)=(dB)x(dA)}];
  \fi
  % compute projection the normal of the polygon on the normal of screen    
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myproj{TD("(nA)o(n)")}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lproj{TD("(nA)o(L)")}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(\myproj)}
  \ifnum\itest>-1 
   \draw[thick] [fill=white,fill opacity=0.2]
   plot[samples at=\poly,variable=\x](p\x) -- cycle; 
  \else
   \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
    \draw[gray,ultra thin] 
    plot[samples at=\poly,variable=\x](p\x) -- cycle;  
   \end{scope}
  \fi
  }}}}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{65}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
    bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
 \pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=2,rotate=30]{isocahedron};
 %\foreach \X in {1,...,\NumVertices}  {\path (p\X) node[above]{\X};}
 \path (p12) node[above]{$D$} -- 
  node[bullet,label=above:$N$](N){}
  (p2) node[above]{$A$}
  (p7) node[left]{$B$} -- 
  node[bullet,label={[xshift=3pt]above:$M$}]{}
  (p11) node[below right]{$C$};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
  \path let \p1=($(N)-(0,0)$) in
   node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,draw,thick,minimum size=2*\y1] 
  (6gon){};
  \path (6gon.corner 1) node[above] {$D$}
   -- node[bullet,label=above:$N$](N'){}
   (6gon.corner 2) node[above] {$A$};
  \draw[thick] (6gon.corner 3) node[left] {$M$} 
   -- node[bullet,label=below right:$O$](O){}
   (6gon.corner 6)
   (O) edge (N');
  \draw ([xshift=-1em]O.center)  |- ([yshift=1em]O.center);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The icosahedron is rotatable in 3d.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,3dtools,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{pics/isocahedron/.style={code={
\path foreach \Coord [count=\X] in 
{(0.,0.,-0.9510565162951536),
(0.,0.,0.9510565162951536),
(-0.85065080835204,0.,-0.42532540417601994),
(0.85065080835204,0.,0.42532540417601994),
(0.6881909602355868,-0.5,-0.42532540417601994),
(0.6881909602355868,0.5,-0.42532540417601994),
(-0.6881909602355868,-0.5,0.42532540417601994),
(-0.6881909602355868,0.5,0.42532540417601994),
(-0.2628655560595668,-0.8090169943749475,-0.42532540417601994),
(-0.2628655560595668,0.8090169943749475,-0.42532540417601994),
(0.2628655560595668,-0.8090169943749475,0.42532540417601994),
(0.2628655560595668,0.8090169943749475,0.42532540417601994)}
  {\Coord coordinate (p\X) \pgfextra{\xdef\NumVertices{\X}}};
 %\message{number of vertices is \NumVertices^^J} 
 % normal of screen 
 \path[overlay] ({sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},
    {-1*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},
    {cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}) coordinate (n)
    ({-sqrt(1/6)},{sqrt(3/6)},{sqrt(2/6)})  coordinate (L); 
 \edef\lstPast{0}
 \foreach \poly in 
 {{2,12,8},{2,8,7},{2,7,11},{2,11,4},{2,4,12},{5,9,1},{6,5,1},
    {10,6,1},{3,10,1},{9,3,1},{12,10,8},{8,3,7},{7,9,11},{11,5,4},{4,6,12},
    {5,11,9},{6,4,5},{10,12,6},{3,8,10},{9,7,3}}
 {
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ione}{{\poly}[0]}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itwo}{{\poly}[1]}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ithree}{{\poly}[2]}
  \path[overlay,3d coordinate={(dA)=(p\itwo)-(p\ione)},
   3d coordinate={(dB)=(p\itwo)-(p\ithree)},
   3d coordinate={(nA)=(dA)x(dB)}] ;
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{sign(TD("(nA)o(p\ione)"))}
  % make sure that the normal points outwards
  \ifnum\jtest<0
   \path[overlay,3d coordinate={(nA)=(dB)x(dA)}];
  \fi
  % compute projection the normal of the polygon on the normal of screen    
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myproj{TD("(nA)o(n)")}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lproj{TD("(nA)o(L)")}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sign(\myproj)}
  \ifnum\itest>-1 
   \draw[thick] [fill=white,fill opacity=0.2]
   plot[samples at=\poly,variable=\x](p\x) -- cycle; 
  \else
   \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
    \draw[gray,ultra thin] 
    plot[samples at=\poly,variable=\x](p\x) -- cycle;  
   \end{scope}
  \fi
  }}}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \XX in {0,10,...,350}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
    bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt}]
 \path (-3.5,-3.5) rectangle (3.5,3.5);
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{60+20*sin(\XX)}{\XX}  
 \pic[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3]{isocahedron};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wait, I really need to come to grips with this: You're saying that LaTeX code, such as provided here, can generate a PDF with embedded 3D rotatable (either manually or animated) graphics? Good Sweet WonderBar! I used to have a project that I always wanted to throw 3D graphs in to make some concepts easier to understand, but it was so far beyond current efforts that I punted. But this... even if it's a mathematical generation... would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I wanted! I just downloaded PGF and TikZ and ran the code, but it didn't work... Where do I suppose to place my pgf_3.1.tds?

Comment: @NowayYesway You need to download `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` from [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools) and put it in the same directory as the main file (or at some other place where TeX can find it).

Comment: @J.Hirsch It is rotatable in the sense that you can choose the projection from 3d to the screen. This is what `\tdplotsetmaincoords{<latitude>}{<longitude>}` from `tikz-3dplot` does, and there are several other packages that do that in LaTeX. What this code does in addition is to decide which faces are behind other faces, i.e. 3d ordering. `asymptote` has means to produce objects that can be rotated in a pdf, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451803. To the best of my knowledge, this cannot yet be done with Ti*k*Z and the other LaTeX graphics packages.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Thank you. So it's still a requirement to have the java/html5 or whatever in the PDF package to do the 3D rendering/rotationgs/explorations. That's oK- I'm really glad to have it clarified. Thank you.

Comment: @J.Hirsch You *can* embed animations. But then you cannot actively rotate stuff. So, yes, if you want to be able to rotate the object at will, you need something special.

Answer (score 5):

Please see if this meets the requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphics, tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
    \SetVertexNoLabel   % <--- This avoids that default $a_0$, .. $b_0$ labels show up
    \grIcosahedral[form=1,RA=3,RB=1.5]

    % Following two lines assign labels to a-like and b-like nodes
    % change it as you prefer
    \AssignVertexLabel{a}{$v_0$, $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$, $v_5$};
    \AssignVertexLabel{b}{$v_6$, $v_7$, $v_8$, $v_9$, $v_{10}$, $v_{11}$};

    % The remaining code is unchanged
    \SetUpEdge[color=white,style={double=black,double distance=2pt}]
    \EdgeInGraphLoop{a}{6}
    \EdgeFromOneToSel{a}{b}{0}{1,5}
    \Edges(a2,b1,b3,b5,a4)
    \Edge(a3)(b3)
    \Edges(a1,b1,b5,a5)
    \Edges(a2,b3,a4)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to @JLDiaz who has given the solution -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183075/197451

Comment: Is there a way to remove the labeled vertices?

Answer (score 1):

At https://github.com/NeilStrickland/groups_and_symmetry there is a full set of teaching material (including LaTeX files) for an undergraduate course on symmetry groups.  The lecture notes contain many tikz diagrams of polyhedra including the icosahedron.

Comment: Can you extract from this documentation the code that answers the question?

Comment: No, I do not have precisely the requested diagram.  But both the OP and other people reading this question are likely to have use for a range of similar diagrams.